# Functions does not recognize variable from a page loaded with require_once 'APPATH (...)'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to load a page with require_once on CodeIgniter but after it loads, if i want to call a variable from it, it will not recognize it. 
Why would this happens? makes no sense

file i want to load:

```
<?php

    $servidorodbc=file(APPPATH.'libraries/odbc.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $dsn=$servidorodbc['0'];
            $user=$servidorodbc['1'];
            $pwd=$servidorodbc['2'];


            if($pwd="''"){
                $pwd="";
            };

            $db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);
    ?>
```

Function where i want it to load:

```
     public function usuarioodbc($codigo,$nif){
            require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/odbc_conn.php');
                    $query = odbc_exec($db, 'select COUNT(*) as counter, Descricao,Codigo, N_Contrib from GP_Mn_Empregados where Codigo ='.$codigo.' AND N_Contrib="'.$nif.'" GROUP BY Descricao,Codigo, N_Contrib');
$resultado = odbc_fetch_array($query);

     if($resultado['counter'] == 1){
                return $resultado['Descricao'];
             }else{
                return false;
        }

    }
```

Error i get :

Message: Undefined variable: db

Comment: Is any of this code INSIDE of a function??? You need to show it if so.

Comment: yes, the second one is a function

Comment: That shouldn't happen, are you sure the error is on the line you show `$query = odbc_exec($db, 'select COUNT(*) ...`???

Comment: yeah i know right...  Yes, it says line 57 which is the line of the variable

Comment: if you required the same file ```odbc_conn.php``` anywhere during runtime before this method is executed the variable won't be available because ```require_once()``` checks if it was included before. if ```$db``` is global inside ```odbc_conn.php``` use ```global $db;``` instead of ```require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/odbc_conn.php');``` if that is the case

Comment: it worked with require

Comment: just can't get why

Comment: yes it would work if you use ```require()``` as i said ```require_once()``` would check first if included before https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: @Talal: Nice catch...

Answer (score 0):

using `require_once()` will include the file only once during runtime.

example:

#### `somefile.php`:

```php
$globalVar = 'somevalue';
```

#### runtime script:

```php
function test1() {
    require_once('somefile.php');
    echo $globalVar; // somevalue
}

test1();

require_once('somefile.php');

echo $globalVar; // undefined

require('somefile.php');

// now $globalVar is in global scope
echo $globalVar; // somevalue
```

undefined the first time because the file it was included before when we called `test1()`
so the file won't get included again and the `$globalVar` is available in the scope of `test1()`